# Error in accessing Data using APIs

Tags: r, api

I can access API data using "curl" on terminal but get error when i use R. Looking for some advice

Curl command:

> curl -H "token:jQyrbzexeCEaWFIDBAwCWqbrkrVQTVhM" "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets"

R command:

> books_key <- "&token=jQyrbzexeCEaWFIDBAwCWqbrkrVQTVhM"
>
> url <- "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets"
>
> req <- fromJSON(paste0(url, books_key))

**Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.**
Usually this error comes when there are spaces in URL (from other similar questions) but in my case there is no space in URL

Some info on using token from website https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted
[image]

Not a R issue because following example of another website works

> movie_key <- "&api-key=b75da00e12d54774a2d362adddcc9bef"
>
> url <- "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/dvd-picks.json?order=by-date"
>
> req <- fromJSON(paste0(url, movie_key))

Comment: have you seen the `rnoaa` package?  `rnoaa::ncdc_datasets(token = "your key")`

Comment: thanks, I will look into it. But, I want to pull data directly from API into R instead of using another package to pull data. Could you look into above error and share what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to pass the token as a header not a query param, e.g. with the `crul` pkg

```
cli <- crul::HttpClient$new(
    url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov", 
    headers = list(token = "yourtoken"))
cli$get(path = "cdo-web/api/v2/datasets")
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your Curl and your R call - in Curl your passing the token as a header variable and in the R call it appears to be a query variable.

Also the NYT call has a query param in the URI so & would be appropriate in the R call.

Comment: ok, any idea where to rightly add the **token** in R command. Above picture gives some info on the token addition but i do not know how to interpret it w.r.t. R